# Selenium get class attribute of element with javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, selenium

I am using using Selenium to write test automation with Javascript. Trying to extract class attributes of a DOM element does not work for me. Here is my code:

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
            withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).
            build();
var usernameField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('username'));
var classes = usernameField.getAttribute('class');
console.log(classes);
```

This prints the following:

```
{ then: [Function: then],
cancel: [Function: cancel],
isPending: [Function: isPending] }
```

Please indicate how to find the attribute values of the element.

Comment: How about we see the HTML of this "usernameField" element?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Found the issue, console.log() was being fired asynchronously before any values were assigned. Forcing it to execute sequentially using then statement fixed the problem.

```
var webdriver = require('selenium-webdriver');
var driver = new webdriver.Builder().
        withCapabilities(webdriver.Capabilities.ie()).
        build();
var usernameField = driver.findElement(webdriver.By.id('username'));
usernameField.getAttribute('class')
.then(function(classes){
    console.log(classes);
 });
```